# Microservices registering Docker internal IP on Eureka instead of public one

Tags: java, docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to register some microservices on Eureka. They're deployed on remote machines and I expected to be able to see the machine's IP on Eureka, but all I can see is a private IP like `172.17.0.8` which is not accessible from outside.

Since these microservices are running on Docker containers I understand I need to tell the service to pick up the Host's IP instead of Docker's but I don't really see how.

I saw this issue on github -> https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/432

and tried:

```
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.ip-address=
```

It doesn't quite work. Is there any way of doing it that doesn't involve adding code to my service or using AWS's API?

Comment: You need to look further down in that issue. For aws specifically, you can get your host's ip from `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`, in case you have spring aws: you can inject `@Value("${public-ipv4}")`, or use those other approaches mentioned there. Basically all of them use that url in the end. If you don't want it in code, do the check outside of it somewhere and use properties to bring it into the code (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/432#issuecomment-134512416 and read those environment vars)

Comment: You can try setting the hostname in the environment variable `eureka.instance.hostname`. But if you are running on aws cloud and your instances are ephemeral, you will have to use instance metadata to populate the environment variable

Comment: I've seen things like: `hostname: ${DOCKER_HOST:localhost}`, although I haven't tried it yet. Is that what you mean @Shibashis?

Comment: That depends on whether you have set DOCKER_HOST on the host. I am suggest adding an environment variable at docker startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to inject the public IP within the Docker container using a small script:

**entrypoint.sh**

```
export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(curl --retry 3 --connect-timeout 2 --max-time 2  -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)

echo $DOCKER_HOST_IP > /var/log/dockerIp.log

exec "$@"
```

Then modifying **Dockerfile** to run it at the beginning:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 9000
ADD service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

CMD bash -c 'source /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh && java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar'
```

The main problem was to export the variable out of the script, for that we're using `source` which is only available in `bash`, that's the reason of the CMD.

This script can be manually placed within the project, although we configured it as an automatic resource download in our maven build:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>https://url/entrypoint.sh</url>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/docker</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: There is another option: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/432#issuecomment-135327850

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on my environments- it was registering with container ID on eureka instead of the hostname. But that is not on AWS so could not call the API for public ip. Below command solved my issue-

```
sudo docker run -i --net=host <dockerregistry_host>/<appName>:tag
```